# What do the partially filled circles on skyvector mean?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

What does a partially filled weather status circle signify on Skyvector.com ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's an indication of how much of the sky is under that weather condition: IMC, marginal VMC, VMC.

Comment: what does a half-filled green circle mean then? half of the sky is VFR and the other half is what?

Comment: Not 100% sure.  I was looking at the weather reports that are pulled up when you hover over a circle, and the reports don't look that different between 1/4 green, 1/2 green, 3/4 green.   Could be how much of the area is under a high ceiling. So VMC, but not fully clear skies.

Comment: Actually the colour indicates condition (green = VMC, blue = Marginal VMC, red = IMC) and the fraction is cloud coverage (empty = clear, full = overcast, fractions in between). It is taken from https://www.1800wxbrief.com/.

Comment: @GJ., it means VFR (green), partly cloudy (1/2).

Comment: 1/4-full circle would mean 1/4 clouds, or 3/4 clouds?

Comment: @gj If you are referring to the circle an the chart above Flying Wing, it is 3/4 clouds.